# sql for limit record group by in derby database

Tags: sql, derby

I want to retrieve ten records only in derby database. I have been searching the tutorial for doing that:

```
select * from (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum,name,effort from (select  name, effort from
(select TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.P_NAME as Name, sum(TBL_TIMESHEET.EFFORT) as effort from
TBL_TIMESHEET join tbl_project_detail on TBL_TIMESHEET.PROJECT_ID = TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.ID group by TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.P_NAME) as New)
as new2)
as new3 
where rownum <= 10
```

I can limit the data to 10 first by using where `rownum <= 10`  at the end, but the problem is that data is not ordered using `order by` clause first so I got 10 random data.

When I put `order by` before the data give `rownum`:

```
select * from (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum,name,effort from 
(select  name, effort from
(select TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.P_NAME as Name, sum(TBL_TIMESHEET.EFFORT) as effort from
TBL_TIMESHEET join tbl_project_detail on TBL_TIMESHEET.PROJECT_ID = TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.ID group by TBL_PROJECT_DETAIL.P_NAME)
as New)
as new2 order by effot desc)
as new3  where rownum <=10
```

It gave error. Its like cannot `group by` when you put the result as inner table for query again, but the requirement for derby is to use row_number. Is first add row_number in inner and use that in where, in next layer. Any one can help? Derby is not support limit. Any other way that I can have 10 record first that I order by ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have been researching and i found like this
to limit in derby by using

```
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

but poor me that support in derby 10.5 and i'm using derby 10.4 bundle with glassfish 2.1 
any one maybe can help with this if i still using 10.4 cuz i'm too afraid for migrated

Comment: can u give full query

Answer (score 1):

You can give the order by clause inside "OVER() "

```
OVER(order by effot desc) AS rownum
```

Comment: No. Derby does not support that: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rreffuncrownumber.html

Comment: i'm sorry thats not working
yes not support that i afraid
its still error 
i'm using derby 10.4